# How do I pass data to a parent class using the super function in java?

Tags: java

How do I create a constructor for the child class which allows me to enter data for the Engine class?

```
abstract class Vehicle {  //parent class
    protected String name;
    protected int numOfWheels;

    public Vehicle(String n, int nw){
        name = n;
        numOfWheels = nw;
    }

    public abstract void drive();
}

class Engine{  // a non public class 
    private String type; 
    private double power;

    public Engine (String t, double p){
        type = t;
        power = p;
    }
}
```

This is the child class which inherits the parent class and also implement an interface class

```
public class MotorCar extends Vehicle implements MoveableListener{ 
    protected String owner;
    protected Engine engine;
    public MotorCar(String n, int nw, String o, Engine e){  //the problem is here
        super(n,nw);
        owner = o;
        engine = e;
    }
    public void drive(){
        System.out.println("Car is moving");
    }
    public boolean isMoveable(){  //do I need to implement the interface method?
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MotorCar myCar = new MotorCar("Mazda 1.5", 4, "Lai Kim Min", "SkyActive", 1.5 ); //problem here too
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. You're already receiving an `Engine` as an argument. Did you want to receive a `type` and `power` and instantiate your `Engine` that way? Just do that if so.

Comment: Do you want to do `new MotorCar("Mazda 1.5", 4, "Lai Kim Min", new Engine("SkyActive", 1.5));`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
MotorCar myCar = new MotorCar("Mazda 1.5", 4, "Lai Kim Min", "SkyActive", 1.5 );
```

with

```
MotorCar myCar = new MotorCar("Mazda 1.5", 4, "Lai Kim Min", new Engine("SkyActive", 1.5));
```

> do I need to implement the interface method?

**Yes**. Java requires that a concrete (non-abstract) class implementing an interface provides the implementation for the interface methods.

I also suggest overriding the `toString` method in `Engine` and `MotorCar` as per your requirement. Shown below is the output after overriding the `toString` method in eclipse IDE's default way:

```
abstract class Vehicle { // parent class
    protected String name;
    protected int numOfWheels;

    public Vehicle(String n, int nw) {
        name = n;
        numOfWheels = nw;
    }

    public abstract void drive();
}

class Engine { // a non public class
    private String type;
    private double power;

    public Engine(String t, double p) {
        type = t;
        power = p;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Engine [type=" + type + ", power=" + power + "]";
    }
}

public class MotorCar extends Vehicle implements MoveableListener {
    protected String owner;
    protected Engine engine;
    private boolean moveable;

    public MotorCar(String n, int nw, String owner, Engine engine, boolean moveable) {
        super(n, nw);
        this.owner = owner;
        this.engine = engine;
        this.moveable = moveable;
    }

    public void drive() {
        System.out.println("Car is moving");
    }

    public boolean isMoveable() {
        return moveable;
    }

    public void setMoveable(boolean moveable) {
        this.moveable = moveable;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MotorCar [owner=" + owner + ", engine=" + engine + ", moveable=" + moveable + ", name=" + name
                + ", numOfWheels=" + numOfWheels + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MotorCar myCar = new MotorCar("Mazda 1.5", 4, "Lai Kim Min", new Engine("SkyActive", 1.5), true);
        System.out.println(myCar);
        System.out.println("is myCar moveable? " + myCar.isMoveable());
        myCar.setMoveable(false);
        System.out.println("is myCar moveable? " + myCar.isMoveable());    
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
MotorCar [owner=Lai Kim Min, engine=Engine [type=SkyActive, power=1.5], moveable=true, name=Mazda 1.5, numOfWheels=4]
is myCar moveable? true
is myCar moveable? false
```

Comment: My tutorial question was to create an interface method that returns a boolean value. 
public boolean isMoveable();

How do I implement this method in the child class?

Comment: Why is the Engine constructor able to access type and power even though they are private attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Your current constructor requires an engine is already created

```
Engine e = new Engine(...);
Vehicle v = new MotorCar(..., e);
```

If you're not extending an Engine class, there's no way to call super to get it

If you want to construct an engine within the vehicle class, you could pass in the engine parts separately

```
public MotorCar(String n, int nw, String o, String t, String p){ 
        super(n,nw);
        owner = o;
        engine = new Engine(t, p);
    }
```

Aside: all vehicles have owners and engines, no?

Comment: yeah, all vehicles should have their owners and engines. Is my code missing something?

Comment: You can't extend more than one class in Java